# How to use live555 to stream a local video in Android

Tags: android, rtsp

I am a rookie at Android and have been working on making Android a streaming server.Now I have known is that live555 can be a media server and be ported to Android.According to many resources, I know how to build  livlib555.so with ndk-build and I have done that.

But the question is that I don't know how to use it.I want to stream some local video files just like that I can easily stream video files in my windows7 pc by run the live555mediaserver.exe(and access it with "rtsp://ip:80/mp4_file_name").I am looking for a same way(or similar) in android.